# Can I use Google Cloud Run to run container images that utilize GPUs for deep learning?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I'm trying to migrate current project from Google Cloud compute instances (virtual machines) to using Google Cloud Run.
Currently, the project consists of multiple containers (mysql, backend, frontend, deep learning processing) and they are all deployed in gcloud vm with docker-compose. the deep learning processing container utilize Nvidia GPU cards on the VM.

I learnt that gcloud run is really powerful and it runs docker containers and auto-scales them when needed. My questions is, if I am to migrate to using Cloud Run, can I do it to the deep learning processing container?

Answer (score 2):

After doing some research I have found that GPUs in Cloud Run for Anthos are available. Other Google products seem to be in the works, but there are no guarantees. You may be better served if you created a feature request, the more specific you are the better.